# How to retrieve the schema of a DBObject?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

In mySQL the `describe` statement can be used to retrieve the schema of a given table, unfortunately I could not locate a similar functionality for the MongoDB java driver :(

Let's say I have I have the flowing BSON documents:

```
{
_id: {$oid:49},
values: { a:10, b:20}
}
,
{
_id: {$oid:50},
values: { b:21, c:31}
}
```

Now let's suppose I do:

```
DBObject obj = cursor.next();
DBObject values_1 = (DBObject) obj.get("values");
```

and the schema should be something like this:

```
>a : int
>b : int
```

and for the next document:

```
DBObject obj = cursor.next();
DBObject values_2 = (DBObject) obj.get("values");
```

the schema should be:

```
>b : int
>c : int
```

Now that I explained what the schema retrial is, can some1 be nice and tell me how to do it?

If it helps, In ma case I only need to know the field names (because the datatype is always the same, but it would be nice also know how to retrieve the datatypes).

---

A work arround, is convert the DBObject to a Map, then the Map to a Set, the Set to an Iterator and extract the attribute names/values... Still have now idea how to extract data types.

this is:

```
    DBObject values_1 = (DBObject) obj.get("values");
    Map _map = values_1.toMap();
//    Set set = _map.entrySet(); // if you want the <key, value> pairs
    Set _set_keys = _map.keySet();
    Iterator _iterator = _set_keys.iterator();
    while (_iterator.hasNext())
         System.out.println("-> " + _iterator.next());
```

Answer (score 1):

A `DBObject` has a method called `keySet` ([documentation)](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.0/org/bson/BSONObject.html#keySet%28%29). You shouldn't need to convert to a `Map` first.

There's no exposed method to determine the underlying BSON data type at this point, so you'd need to investigate using `instanceof` or `getClass` to determine the underlying data type of the `Object` that is returned from `get`.

If you look at the [source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/401490a9be25d0183b23bc04d4a12afb28abc255/src/main/org/bson/BasicBSONObject.java) code for `BasicBSONObject` for example, you'll see how the helper functions that cast do some basic checks and then force the cast.