# Field's datatype of collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How to get field information of a collection in mongodb.

information I am looking for are

- field name
- data type

Comment: In a schema less DB, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to loop over all the documents and figure out what the used names are, and which types each specific field uses. MongoDB does not have a schema, so there is no short cut to fetch this. Be also aware that each field's value can have totally different data types as well—another one of MongoDB's strenghts.

To figure out some statistics, such as field names, the following script can help:

```
mr = db.runCommand({
  "mapreduce" : "things",
  "map" : function() {
    for (var key in this) { emit(key, null); }
  },
  "reduce" : function(key, stuff) { return null; }, 
  "out": "things" + "_keys"
})
```

Then run distinct on the resulting collection so as to find all the keys:

```
db[mr.result].distinct("_id");
```

But there is no way to also include the field types with a Map/Reduce job like this.

Comment: If there was structure to the document, the code would need to be more complex.

Answer (score 0):

You can't determine the schema of a collection. E**ach of the objects of an collection might have a different schema**, you should be aware of this.

[I made a similar question a few months ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134005/how-to-retrieve-the-schema-of-a-dbobject) , in the post you can find how to retrieve the schema of an object using the java programing language; However, to the best of my knowledge, the is no way to retrieve the data types other than try to cast the objects ([this is the way the BasicBsonObjects do i](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/401490a9be25d0183b23bc04d4a12afb28abc255/src/main/org/bson/BasicBSONObject.java)t).

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB supports dynamic schema, and there is no inbuilt feature for schema introspection or analysis as at MongoDB 2.4.

However .. it is possible to infer the schema by inspecting using a Map/Reduce across either a sample of documents or the entire collection.

There are a few open source tools which package this approach up in a helpful interface, for example:

- [Schema.js](http://skratchdot.com/projects/mongodb-schema/) - extends the `mongo` shell with `collection.schema()` prototypes
- [Variety](https://github.com/variety/variety) - runs as a standalone script

I like the approach of `schema.js`, and include it in my [`~/mongorc.js`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/#mongo-mongorc-file) startup file so it is available in my `mongo` shell sessions.

By default `schema.js` analyzes up to 50 documents in a collection and returns the results inline.  There is a `limit` option to inspect more (or even all) documents in a collection, and it supports the Map/Reduce [`out` options](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#mapreduce-out-cmd) so results can optionally be saved or merged with an output collection.